# How to calculate height of a String?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to adjust the cell height resize to fit the UILabel text, but it is not working..

```
var mySize = CGFloat()
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cellView

        cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
        cell.myLabel.bounds.size.height = self.mySize

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        func heightForLabel(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat
        {
            let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFloat.max))
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
            label.font = font
            label.text = items[indexPath.row]

            label.sizeToFit()
            return label.frame.height
        }

        let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 30)
        let detailHeight = heightForLabel(items[indexPath.row], font: font!, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width)

        self.mySize = detailHeight

        return CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 358 + detailHeight)
    }
```

Any suggestions what to do here? Should i do it another way? Please, I need help.. The problem is that the UILabel text is set in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, and `items` is an array for strings.

This is my project file, if someone watch to take a look at it:
http://www.filedropper.com/test_37

Comment: Have you set yourself as as the collectionView's delegate? Also, it should be `return label.frame.size.height` in the `heightForLabel` function

Comment: @mbo42 - Yea, still not working..

Comment: Is the function getting called? What results are you getting? Btw, in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you shouldn't need to modify the cell's frame.

Comment: @mbo42 Updated question with project link. Maybe you want to take a look at it!

Answer (score 5):

Why not try this in ObjC

```
 [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, maxHeight)
                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                               attributes:nil context:nil]
```

This will give CGRect. Get the height from it. set font size etc in attributes parameter.

**UPDATE**

In place of this

```
let detailHeight = heightForLabel(items[indexPath.row], font: font!, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width)
```

Use this

```
let height = items[indexPath.row].boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(CGFloat.max,UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font!], context: nil).size.height
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How and where do i use this?

Comment: That did not work either.. http://s17.postimg.org/6t42d2zzj/Simulator_Screen_Shot_14_Dec_2015_10_54_55.png

Comment: Added a link to my project if you would like to look at it: http://www.filedropper.com/test_37

Comment: Not on a laptop currently so taking simple guesses to atleast exclude the possibilities. 

Lines property for UILabel should be 0 

Shouldn't set explicit height for label in storyboard/xib

Comment: You are not using AutoLayout. Currently you have to set the frame for UIImageView & UILabel yourself. That's what's missing. Whatever size you've created them in Interface Builder, they will retain it during runtime too. Either use the calculations for string height to set their frame in the cell or use autolayout to do it for you.

Comment: I´m all blank. I dont understand this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like that but I have implemented it in different way. Here is the sample of code you can do it.

```
 let desiredWidth: CGFloat = tableView.bounds.size.width
 let label: UILabel = UILabel()

 let desiredString = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."

 label.text = desiredString
 label.numberOfLines = 0;
 label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
 let size: CGSize = label.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(desiredWidth, CGFloat.max))

 print("Label height you can set to your cell: \(size.height)")
```

Comment: I get this in the output: http://s23.postimg.org/ydrqqcutn/Screen_Shot_2015_12_14_at_10_27_08.png - But how do i set the label height?

Comment: You have to calculate it while reloading your tableview, so you can use it in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: See when you reload your tableview then **tableview delegate methods** are called `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is one of its delegate method you have to return `CGFloat` value to this so you could return above value

Answer (score 2):

**Crate an String extension**

```
extension String {
    func heightOfString(usingFont font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let fontAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
        let size = self.size(attributes: fontAttributes)
        return size.height
    }
}
```

get the height of the string as follows

```
let str = "Hello world"
let strHgt = str.heightOfString(usingFont: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12))
```

Answer (score 1):

I create this method for getting height of a label. You need to provide label's static Width and label's font

```
func dynamicHeight(font: UIFont, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let calString = NSString(string: self)
    let textSize = calString.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(width, CGFloat.max), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
    return textSize.height
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In swift 5 you can use this code

```
let text = arrRatingData[indexPath.row].comment
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.5)
let size = CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.width - 80, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin
let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
let height = NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: attributes, context: nil).height
```

Comment: Working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
   NSString *yourText = @"Your string";
    CGSize lableWidth = CGSizeMake(300, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize requiredSize = [yourText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"CALIBRI" size:17] constrainedToSize:lableWidth lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    int calculatedHeight = requiredSize.height;
    return (float)calculatedHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your code, and I was able to solve it.

Firstly, on line 71 in your `ViewController` class:

```
let height = items[indexPath.row].boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(CGFloat.max, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font!], context: nil).size.height
```

You accidentally set CGFloat.max as width and the width as height. It should be:

```
CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, CGFloat.max)
```

I'd say it's better practice to use the width of the view that the cell is directly contained in (the `collectionView`), but that's just my personal opinion.

Secondly, you need to enable AutoLayout. Go to your `Main.storyboard` file and make sure `Use Auto Layout` is selected.

[image: Enable AutoLayout]

Now you need to add `constraints`. (You can read more about AutoLayout and constraints [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html))

There are different ways to add constraints. The easiest way is to control click a UI element and drag the mouse to the element you want to set a constraint to.

You need to add the following constraints for your cell:

```
ImageView.top = cell.top
ImageView.leading = cell.leading
ImageView.trailing = cell.trailing
ImageView.bottom = MyLabel.top + 8 (your padding)
MyLabel.leading = cell.leading
MyLabel.trailing = cell.trailing
MyLabel.bottom = cell.bottom
```

And these for your CollectionView

```
CollectionView.top = view.top
CollectionView.leading = view.leading
CollectionView.trailing = view.trailing
CollectionView.bottom = view.bottom
```

I've attached the project, modified with AutoLayout here below.

[Modified project](http://www.filedropper.com/testautolayout)

**Edit:**

Approach 2 - without AutoLayout.

This could also be achieved without using AutoLayout by manually updating the cell's label height in `collectionView:willDisplayCell:`. I'm sure there are better alternatives, I'd personally try `AutoResizingMasks` before this approach.

[Project without AutoLayout](http://www.filedropper.com/test2_5)

Comment: Nice work! A questions; Are you able to do this without using Auto Layout? Because i have a application made without Auto Layout..

Comment: I guess you could manually set the frames for ImageView and MyLabel  after making the calculations. Note that you don't need to implement AutoLayout for all views just because you checked the box. You could choose just to do it for that ViewController.

Comment: Could you also provide a example project for this solution without Auto Layout? It would be really helpful, as i have never ever used Auto Layout before :)

Comment: Okay, [here you go](http://www.filedropper.com/test2_5). I got it working by moving the height setting of the label in `willDisplayCell`. I also added caching of the calculated heights for performance reasons. I'd still recommend using AutoLayout over this approach though.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you strongly recommend that i use Auto Layout? Will using auto layout make this more stable, or? In that case, how do i only use Auto Layout for that view controller, if i have multiple view controller with tab bar controller and navigation controllers, but want to set Auto Layout for only that view controller?

Comment: I'd say it's easier to rely on the system to handle dynamic sizing. Also, it makes changing layouts much easier as you just need to change the constraints, which really helps in larger scale projects. In the end it's up to you to decide what suits you/your project best. If you don't want AutoLayout for other ViewControllers/Views, you simply don't need to set constraints in them. :)

Comment: I have been using this all the time: http://s14.postimg.org/lb6dbwjmp/Screen_Shot_2015_12_15_at_10_40_59.png - Can i use Auto Layout for 1 view controller, and the other 10 controllers i can use this Autoresizing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97952/discussion-between-mbo42-and-roduck-nickes).

Comment: Good idea! Have sent you a message now.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String{
  
  func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont)  ->  CGFloat {

        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)

        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
        return ceil(boundingBox.height)
    }}
```